# Proxy Server that supports smart pipelining/multiplexing

Tags: python, http, proxy, twisted, pipelining

So, I want to develop a proxy server that when contacted checks the size of what it will be downloading to proxy (using head most likely) and if it's over a set size it splits the download of the request via pipelining and using Range into generally good sized (1 megabyte or possibly using a config file) segments.  Then as it downloads it and rotates the pipes I want it to feed back to it's client what it gets (in order), so that if it is say a stream of media it will be able to play it easily.  The goal is to split too large ones into pipelines and the smaller ones to leave them alone.  I am sorta unsure where to start.  I did find other proxy servers (polipo) that could do pipelining/multiplexing as mentioned but none worked as outlined above.  So A. does anything exist that does it and B. how would i get started? (I would prefer to work in python if possible)

Answer (score 1):

I would look at twisted http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ it is an great event based networking library for python.  It takes a bit of getting used to, but it does this kind of thing very well.